# HDTV and Apple TV into Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one

I currently have my Apple TV routed through the HDMI input of my Xbox One. If I bought an over-the-air HDTV solution like http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/over-the-air-tv (which seems to connect via USB), could I select between HDTV and AppleTV? Or does the Xbox One only expect one external video source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have that exact setup and yes you simply chose the provider in OneGuide to switch between the two sources.